# Couldn't load file in neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I used the following comnands in neo4j, but the system always responds the following error message.

"Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/import/Tokyo_subway_system.csv ()"

Here is my script:

```
load csv with headers from "file:///Tokyo_subway_system.csv" as csvLine
create (s:Station {id: toInteger(csvLine.id), station_No: csvLine.station_No, station_Name: csvLine.station_Name, station_English: csvLine.station_English, line_Name: csvLine.line_Name ,line_English: csvLine.line_English, latitude: csvLine.latitude, longitade: csvLine.longitade})
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your $NEO4J_HOME/import/ folder in your server or local directory. Then copy that file Tokyo_subway_system.csv in that directory. If you have multiple versions of neo4j installed, ensure that you are on the right neo4j home directory.